# How to go about having a Full-time Job offer after internship?

Tags: job-offer, internship, fulltime

I currently am a Information Systems Major who is a senior. I was able to intern at a great well-known company which is Top 30 on the Fortune 500 list. I ended up receiving a job offer from this company, and I still do not know what to do. The HR department told me that I have until April to decide if I want to take it. But... My managers are both asking me whether or not I want it.

1. I really like interning at the place, I have learned a lot. Also I believe it would be a great entry level position for myself to learn.

Here is where it gets challenging.

1. I believe that I can receive a better offer before I graduate in May
2. I do not really want to relocate yet, unless I get offered a better wage.
3. I ended up doing the internship in the summer, and I was able to work from home for that company during the Fall, and they kept me on as an intern.
4. It is the last weeks of the internship now for the fall, and my managers are talking about a Spring Internship for me WFH again with coming to the office every other week.

**My question:** How do I convey to my managers that I like the internship, and their company but I am still undecided on the offer? Also does that make me a bad person if I were to not accept the offer after interning for a year at the company?

Comment: From your question i couldn't ascertain if the company you intern with (Top 30 of F500) is the one that expended the offer of employment?

Comment: @Strader Yes the company that offered me the job was the company I interned at which is top 30 on the F500 list.

Comment: This sounds like a great career start option.What is the reason you may decline the offer? Were you approached by another company?

Comment: @Strader I received a different offer, and I also do not want to relocate at this point in my personal life.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I convey to my managers that I like the internship, and their company but I am still undecided on the offer?

Just say that what you are telling us here. Express that you really like the company and what you have done and learned there. You can then tell them that, as you are about to graduate, you rather finish (or close to) your studies before considering to fully commit to that offer.

You could also take advantage of the fact that the official deadline they offered is on April, and say that you wish to have that agreed time period to consider the offer.

I also advice you to give a good thought to this one, so you can be less uncertain about your doubts on this job and your career choices, and perhaps be able to give them an answer before that last date.

I also suggest you to look for other jobs, so you can then compare them and decide for yourself what you desire.

> Also does that make me a bad person if I were to not accept the offer after interning for a year at the company?

**Not at all.** You have the right to decide what jobs you want and what others you don't. As long as you turn down the offer in a polite and professional way there in no problem in doing so.

Comment: +1 Dark. To add, although the formal offer decision deadline is April, the reason why your managers are interested in a soft decision now is because they want to include you as part of their teams moving forward. If you say yes now, I can almost guarantee that they are planning for you in a big way.

Comment: @FrankFYC, depends on the company. I also interned at a Fortune 500 company and where you got placed as a full employee was intentionally never the same department you interned in. They wanted new hires to diversify their experience. Verylikely the managers are just excited their intern got an offer and want to know what OP has planned for his future.

Answer (score -2):

Recognizing your expert objectives and finding a compensating temporary job that lives up to your desires will be more gainful to your ability improvement and future vocation yearnings than tolerating only any entry level position that is accessible.
Temporary jobs are intended to get ready candidates for future employments and vocations; and finding an entry level position that will enable you to achieve your expert objectives will likewise help you in being a more aggressive applicant in your future pursuit of employment.